# Django save abuser profile object when user registered

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-registration

Hi I have a custom`UserProfile` model which I will be using for storing user data specific to my app:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I am using `django-registration` to resister and login users.

My question is - what is the best way to auto-save a `UserProfile` object when an `auth.User` is  saved? I can assume that all custom fields on the `UserProfile` model can be saved as null and updated later.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Signals could be a good option. So, whenever the User object is saved it would create an User Profile

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

def _create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(_create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Should the `create_user_profile` method not be indented?

Comment: Oh no...I should have used proper name conventions. Its not a class method, its visible globally so, you can register it with your signal.

Answer (score 0):

To create a user profile if it does not exist yet: Put this in your profile's model file:

```
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

And use e.g. `request.user.profile` when you want to access it.